# How do I rotate a group of vertices without deforming its shape?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Does anybody know the hotkey combination to rotate a group of vertices 45° in edit mode without deforming the cylinder shape? I forgot this important tool, I remember that I could constrain the axes with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

[image]

BTW see below the screen shot to understand better what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its called *[Shear](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html)* and is accessible through the hotkey <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> or the menu entry
*Object/Mesh/Curve/Surface* ‣ *Transform* ‣ *Shear*